# Spring security not redirecting to login page when users is not authenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to block access to pages in my website, but the security config below doesn't restrict access to private pages.

My Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private UserService detailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/passwordrequest/**", "/initSystem").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("email").permitAll().and()
            .logout().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(detailsService);
    }
}
```

I have got a controller for `/login` that puts the user onto the model so that I can assess their information. I have also implemented `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` as required.

Please advise on what could be going wrong. (If there is some specific code you would like me to add let me know)

Comment: why don't you simply add a atPreauthorize in your Controller methods whichever you want to secure. Do you want a sample?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `@Preauthorized @RequestMapping(value = "/submitted/{assessmentId}", method = RequestMethod.POST) public String setStatus........`?

Comment: Something like this '@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")'

Comment: If I do that do I still need my security config?

Comment: Yes. This is just to instruct spring-security to instruct redirecting to login page, mentioned in securityconfig. Also, I would prefer using '@Secured' in DAO and Service layer, and '@Preauthorize' in Controller.

Comment: Just gave that a go, but the controller method is still running without an `ROLE_ADMIN` user authenticating first.

Comment: Then your setup is wrong, I don't know much about security-config in Java, I know in XML, maybe someone else can help you out then. But the preauthorize stays.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have spring security filter configured in your web.xml to intercept all your requests for securizing..

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your private page in your config? you need to have that config.
Example:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/adminpage/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/privatepage/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and().formLogin();
```

Comment: Is that not what `.anyRequest().authenticated()` does? Any other requests need to be authenticated? I will try adding the `.access` to that.

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn't see that. But i think about Anonymous Authentication.